# Copying files without logging in as root

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to copy a few files over to the /var/www/ folder. How might I do this if I am not logged in as root. I know I can jump on terminal and do sudo su and get to root but I am then not sure how I might copy my files from there. Or if there is a way to allow a copy and paste with the root password using the GUI file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the GUI, you can run Nautilus with sudo

```
# gksudo nautilus
```

For easier access, if you use this alot, right-click on your applications menu, pick `Edit Menus` and add an item to System Tools with `gksudo nautilus` as the command.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo cp ~/path/to/file /var/www/`

Answer (score 0):

> You can open the File Explorer of Ubuntu i.e. "`nautilus`" as `root`.

```
sudo nautilus
```

Now you have the full freedom to do anything anywhere.

You just need to log in as root only once, and no need of `sudo` every time to copy, move, create or delete any file which needs root permission.

Hope, it might help...